# magento 1.9x layout setting - single product page

Tags: custom-options, css, product-view, product-page, page-layouts

especially magento geeks, I need a lil help. how can I move in stock, price, color switcher & add to cart option above description, tags & custom tap? 
[image]

```
    <?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $helper_richsnippets = $this->helper('porto/richsnippets');
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $code  = $store->getCode();
?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
    $product_type = $_product->getTypeId();
    $enabled_richsnippets = ($helper_richsnippets->isEnabled() && $product_type !== "grouped");
    $price_properties = "";

    if($enabled_richsnippets){
        $price_properties = $helper_richsnippets->getPriceProperties($_product);
    }

    $enable_addtocart_sticky = Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/enable_addtocart_sticky",$code);
    $move_product_tab = Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/move_product_tab",$code);
    $sticky_header = "";
    if(!Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/header/sticky_header", $code))
        $sticky_header = "no-sticky-header";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view <?php if($move_product_tab): ?>moved-tab<?php endif;?>" <?php if($enabled_richsnippets): ?><?php echo $helper_richsnippets->getProductItemscope(); ?><?php endif; ?>>
    <div class="product-essential">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <div class="no-display">
            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        </div>
<?php
if($enable_addtocart_sticky){
?>
        <div class="sticky-product hide <?php echo $sticky_header; ?>">
            <div class="container">
<?php
    $aspect_ratio = Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/aspect_ratio", $code);
    $ratio_width = 600;
    $ratio_height = 600;
    if(Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/ratio_width", $code))
        $ratio_width = Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/ratio_width", $code);
    if(!$aspect_ratio){
        if(Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/ratio_height", $code))
            $ratio_height = Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/ratio_height", $code);
    }
    $ratio = $ratio_height / $ratio_width;
    $ratio_width = 50;
    $ratio_height = $ratio_width * $ratio;
?>
                <div class="sticky-image">
                    <img src="<?php if($aspect_ratio):?><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(50);?><?php else: ?><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($ratio_width,$ratio_height); ?><?php endif; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"/>
                </div>
                <div class="sticky-detail">
                    <div class="product-name-area">
                        <h2 class="product-name"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h2>
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, false, '_clone') ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php 
                    if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Review')):
                    ?>
                    <?php 
                        $review_html = $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($product, 'short');
                        if($review_html){
                            echo $review_html;
                        }else{
                    ?>
                        <div class="ratings">
                            <div class="rating-box">
                                <div class="rating" style="width:0"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php                            
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <div class="ratings">
                            <div class="rating-box">
                                <div class="rating" style="width:0"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if($enabled_richsnippets): ?>
                    <?php if ($this->getReviewsCount()): ?>
                        <span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
                            <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="<?php echo $this->getRatingSummary(); ?>"/>
                            <meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="<?php echo $this->getReviewsCount(); ?>" />
                            <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="100"/>
                            <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="0"/>
                        </span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
                        <p class="availability in-stock"><span>(<?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?>)</span></p>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span>(<?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?>)</span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
                    <div class="add-to-cart">
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><i class="icon-cart"></i><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
}
?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="product-img-box col-sm-<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/product_image_size", $code); ?> <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/thumbnail_image_type", $code); ?>">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="product-shop col-sm-<?php echo 12-Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/product_image_size", $code); ?>">
            <?php
                if (Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/prev_next",$code)){
            ?>
                <div class="prev-next-products">
                    <?php $_prev = Mage::helper('porto')->getPreviousProduct(); ?>
                    <?php $_next = Mage::helper('porto')->getNextProduct(); ?>

                    <?php if($_prev): ?>
                    <div class="product-nav product-prev">
                        <a href="<?php echo $_prev->getProductUrl();?>" title="<?php echo $this->__("Previous Product"); ?>">
                            <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/prev_text",$code); ?>
                        </a>
                        <div class="product-pop theme-border-color">
                            <?php
                            $image_src = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_prev, 'image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(80);
                            ?>
                            <img class="product-image" src="<?php echo $image_src; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Previous');?>"/>
                            <h3 class="product-name"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_prev, $_prev->getName(), 'name') ?></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if($_next): ?>
                    <div class="product-nav product-next">
                        <a class="product-next" href="<?php echo $_next->getProductUrl();?>" title="<?php echo $this->__("Next Product"); ?>"><?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/next_text",$code); ?></a>
                        <div class="product-pop theme-border-color">
                            <?php
                            $image_src = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_next, 'image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(80);
                            ?>
                            <img class="product-image" src="<?php echo $image_src; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Previous');?>"/>
                            <h3 class="product-name"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_next, $_next->getName(), 'name') ?></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
                <div class="product-name">
                    <h1 <?php if($enabled_richsnippets): ?>itemprop="name"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
                </div>
                <?php if($enabled_richsnippets): ?>
                <?php
                    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
                    $summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($_product->getId());
                ?>
                <?php if ($summaryData['reviews_count']): ?>
                    <span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" class="no-display">
                        <span itemprop="ratingValue"><?php echo $summaryData['rating_summary']; ?></span>
                        <span itemprop="reviewCount"><?php echo $summaryData['reviews_count']; ?></span>
                        <span itemprop="bestRating">100</span>
                        <span itemprop="worstRating">0</span>
                    </span>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>
                <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                    <div class="short-description">
                        <h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?></h2>
                        <div class="std" <?php if($enabled_richsnippets): ?>itemprop="description"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif;?>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <div <?php if($enabled_richsnippets) echo $helper_richsnippets->getOfferItemscope(); ?>>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data'); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml(); ?>
                        <?php echo $price_properties; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
                    <?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
                        <p class="email-friend"><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></a></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if($sku = $_product->getSku()): ?>
                        <?php if($enabled_richsnippets): ?><meta itemprop="productID" content="sku:<?php echo $sku; ?>" /><?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>
                </div>
                <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                    <div class="clearer"></div>
                    <div class="add-to-box">
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                            <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
                <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <div class="clearer"></div>
                    <div class="add-to-box">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
                <?php endif;?>
                <div class="clearer"></div>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addthis_sharetool'); ?>
            </div>

        </div>
        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
        <?php endif;?>
    </form>
<?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('ajaxcart/addtocart/enableproduct') && (Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getModuleName() == "catalog") || (Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getModuleName() == "quickview")): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                if (!url) {
                    url = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').attr('action');
                }
                if(url.indexOf("wishlist/index/cart") != -1){
                    url = url.replace("wishlist/index/cart","ajaxcart/index/add"); // New Code
                } else {
                    url = url.replace("checkout/cart","ajaxcart/index"); // New Code
                }
                url = url.replace("http://", "//");
                url = url.replace("https://", "//");
                var data = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize();
                data += '&isAjax=1';
                var is_quickview = false;
                if(jQuery("body").hasClass("quickview-index-view")){
                    is_quickview = true;
                }
                if(is_quickview)
                    window.parent.jQuery("#loading-mask").show();
                else
                    jQuery('#loading-mask').show();
                try {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url : url,
                        dataType : 'json',
                        type : 'post',
                        data : data,
                        success : function(data) {
                            if(is_quickview)
                                window.parent.jQuery('#loading-mask').hide();
                            else
                                jQuery('#loading-mask').hide();
                            if(data.status == 'ERROR'){
                                if(is_quickview)
                                    window.parent.alert(data.message.replace("<br/>",""));
                                else
                                    alert(data.message.replace("<br/>",""));
                            }else{
                                if(is_quickview){
                                    if(window.parent.jQuery('.header-container .mini-cart')){
                                        window.parent.jQuery('.header-container .mini-cart').replaceWith(data.toplink);
                                    }
                                    if(window.parent.jQuery('.fixed-header .mini-cart')){
                                        window.parent.jQuery('.fixed-header .mini-cart').replaceWith(data.toplink);
                                    }
                                    if(window.parent.jQuery('.sticky-header .mini-cart')){
                                        window.parent.jQuery('.sticky-header .mini-cart').replaceWith(data.toplink);
                                    }
                                    if(window.parent.jQuery('.col-right .block.block-cart')){
                                        window.parent.jQuery('.col-right .block.block-cart').replaceWith(data.cart_sidebar);
                                    }
                                    window.parent.jQuery('#after-loading-success-message #success-message-container .msg-box').html(data.message);
                                    <?php $autoclose = Mage::getStoreConfig('ajaxcart/addtocart/autoclose', $code);?>
                                    ajaxcart_sec = <?php echo ($autoclose && is_numeric($autoclose))?$autoclose:5; ?>;
                                    timer_sec = ajaxcart_sec;
                                    window.parent.jQuery('#after-loading-success-message').fadeIn(200);
                                    ajaxcart_timer = setInterval(function(){
                                        timer_sec --;
                                        window.parent.jQuery('#after-loading-success-message .timer').html(timer_sec);
                                    },1000)
                                    setTimeout(function(){
                                        window.parent.jQuery('#after-loading-success-message').fadeOut(200);
                                        clearTimeout(ajaxcart_timer);
                                        setTimeout(function(){
                                            window.parent.jQuery('#after-loading-success-message .timer').html(ajaxcart_sec);
                                        }, 1000);
                                    },ajaxcart_sec*1000);
                                }
                                else {
                                    if(jQuery('.header-container .mini-cart')){
                                        jQuery('.header-container .mini-cart').replaceWith(data.toplink);
                                    }
                                    if(jQuery('.fixed-header .mini-cart')){
                                        jQuery('.fixed-header .mini-cart').replaceWith(data.toplink);
                                    }
                                    if(jQuery('.sticky-header .mini-cart')){
                                        jQuery('.sticky-header .mini-cart').replaceWith(data.toplink);
                                    }
                                    if(jQuery('.col-right .block.block-cart')){
                                        jQuery('.col-right .block.block-cart').replaceWith(data.cart_sidebar);
                                    }
                                    jQuery('#after-loading-success-message #success-message-container .msg-box').html(data.message);
                                    <?php $autoclose = Mage::getStoreConfig('ajaxcart/addtocart/autoclose', $code);?>
                                    ajaxcart_sec = <?php echo ($autoclose && is_numeric($autoclose))?$autoclose:5; ?>;
                                    timer_sec = ajaxcart_sec;
                                    jQuery('#after-loading-success-message').fadeIn(200);
                                    ajaxcart_timer = setInterval(function(){
                                        timer_sec --;
                                        jQuery('#after-loading-success-message .timer').html(timer_sec);
                                    },1000)
                                    setTimeout(function(){
                                        jQuery('#after-loading-success-message').fadeOut(200);
                                        clearTimeout(ajaxcart_timer);
                                        setTimeout(function(){
                                            jQuery('#after-loading-success-message .timer').html(ajaxcart_sec);
                                        }, 1000);
                                    },ajaxcart_sec*1000);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                }                
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }
            } else {
                if(jQuery('#product-options-wrapper'))
                    jQuery('#product-options-wrapper').scrollToMe();
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
    </script>
<?php else : ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            } else {
                if(jQuery('#product-options-wrapper'))
                    jQuery('#product-options-wrapper').scrollToMe();
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
        //]]>
        </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
                var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                // Remove custom datetime validators
                for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                    if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                        delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                    }
                }

                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            } else {
                if(jQuery('#product-options-wrapper'))
                    jQuery('#product-options-wrapper').scrollToMe();
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    </script>
    </div>

    <div class="product-collateral">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products'); ?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $("body.quickview-index-view .no-rating a, body.quickview-index-view .ratings a").off('click').on("click",function(e){
            window.parent.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
            window.parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
        });
    <?php
    if($enable_addtocart_sticky){
    ?>
        p_scrolled = false;
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if(400<$(window).scrollTop() && !p_scrolled){
                $('.sticky-product').removeClass("hide");
                p_scrolled = true;
            }
            if(400>=$(window).scrollTop() && p_scrolled){
                $('.sticky-product').addClass("hide");
                p_scrolled = false;
            }
        });
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    if($move_product_tab){
    ?>
        $(".product-info").before($(".product-tabs"));
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: It would be better to include the code of that file in question. Most people would not be comfortable to follow a link that downloads a '.rar' file. It  will also work in case link goes dead in future.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using custom theme. Without looking at your `view.phtml` file it will be hard to tell what to move, but I will give it a try.

If you go to your `[your_theme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` file you will find something similar to this:

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
        <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                <dd class="tab-container">
                    <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

This is copied from `rwd` theme.

You can move this whole thing below the `add to cart` and `additional option` block.

Comment: please check the post update

Comment: can you paste whole code in qst plez.

Answer (score 0):

In the code which you have provided, in place of short description it is showing those tabs inside div class='short-description'. And there is one div class='product-info'. So just move div with class='product-info' above the short-description div.

I think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Try moving lines 197 through 219 (seen here):**

```
<?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                <div class="clearer"></div>
                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                        <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
            <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <div class="clearer"></div>
                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>
            <div class="clearer"></div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addthis_sharetool'); ?>
```

**To just before the current snippet of 181 through 186 (seen here):**

```
<div class="product-info">
                <div <?php if($enabled_richsnippets) echo $helper_richsnippets->getOfferItemscope(); ?>>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml(); ?>
                    <?php echo $price_properties; ?>
                </div>
```

**So new version of lines 181 through 208 will be:**

```
                <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                <div class="clearer"></div>
                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                        <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
            <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <div class="clearer"></div>
                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>
            <div class="clearer"></div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addthis_sharetool'); ?>
            <div class="product-info">
                <div <?php if($enabled_richsnippets) echo $helper_richsnippets->getOfferItemscope(); ?>>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml(); ?>
                    <?php echo $price_properties; ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: it did most of the trick but product price and stock is in buttom now and one of the tab is missing, can you please help me out with this! it would really appreciate it!

Comment: anyone??????????